# Current home launcher is not supported by Badges library Android

Tags: android, badge

This is my code

```
int badgeCount = 3;
try {
    Badges.setBadge(ProviderHomepage.this, badgeCount);
    Log.d("BadgeSUCCESS", "BadgeSUCCESS");

} catch (BadgesNotSupportedException badgesNotSupportedException) {
    Log.d("BadgeERROROROROROR", badgesNotSupportedException.getMessage());
}
```

Manifest file app icon is my icon of app

```
<application
      android:icon="@drawable/logofour"
                     />

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}    

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bindaspunch.my.bindaspunch"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim'] } }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/simple-side-drawer2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'
    //    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso:picasso:2.5.2.4b'

    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"    
    compile 'com.github.arturogutierrez:badges:1.0.5@aar'
}
```

The code Reference is

https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Badges

there is an error of having Current home "launcher is not supported by Badges library" in my logcat and i can't change the app icon;

the error remains when i remove app icon from Manifest class... what are the changes than..

i m trying this till Yesterday  but it has issue and i can't use this code, kindely help me out of this issue...
sorry for my english and thnx in advance ...

Comment: Which launcher, OS and device you have?

Comment: i have samsung gt-l9082 mobile

Comment: Samsung default launcher supports the Badges...

Comment: the badges show from one activity but when i use the same code from another activity the badges not show on app icon'

Comment: Copy both codes, 1 that is working and 1 that is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200930/badges-on-app-icon-code-runs-on-one-activity-but-not-in-all-other-activity

Comment: I have the same issue with pixel